# Invalid IAM Instance Profile name - Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am trying to create IAM role via cloudformation. When I execute the cloudformation template I am getting the following the error.

```
Invalid IAM Instance Profile name
```

Here is the code snippet of cloudformation

```
     Role: 
        Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
        Properties: 
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - 
                Effect: "Allow"
                Principal: 
                  Service: 
                    - "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                Action: 
                    - "sts:AssumeRole"
          Path: "/"
    Policies: 
        Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
        Properties: 
          PolicyName: "policy"
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - 
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:PutObjectTagging
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:GetObjectTagging
                  - s3:DeleteObject
                  - s3:DeleteObjectTagging
                Resource: 
                  - arn:aws:s3:::s3-bucket/*
                  - arn:aws:s3:::s3-bucket/*
          Roles: 
            - Ref: Role
    RootInstanceProfile: 
        Type: "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
        Properties: 
          Path: "/"
          Roles: 
            - Ref: "Role"
```

Need help on resolve this one.

Comment: Remove the double quotes around Role in the last line. Since you are looking for a resource created via CloudFormation template, you shouldn't use double quotes for the name of the resource.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 thanks for the response. Lets try this option.